# How can I make clicking on an iTunes (itms) link in Firefox open the link in iTunes?

Tags: firefox, itunes

When I click on an itpc link in Firefox, e.g.

itpc://rss.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.xml

it brings focus to iTunes but doesn't change what's displayed there.  Does anyone know what's going on?

I found these related pages, and something I did brought me closer (getting iTunes to open at all), but I still can't get iTunes to open the URL.

```
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1111530
http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-35577.html
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into "Tools > Options > Applications" and searched for "itms", and selected "Use iTunes (default)".  I now see the expected behavior, that is, I subscribe to the podcast and its starts downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is a Firefox problem. On my system, that link launched from both Firefox and IE 7 brings focus to iTunes and the podcast starts to download, but the view doesn't change. If I switch to the Podcasts page, the new podcast is listed there.

Strangely enough, if I go to iTunes and click "Advance > Subscribe to Podcast" and use that link, then the view does automatically change.